# A Lebesgue measure condition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\{B(x_j,r_j)\}_{j=1}^{n}$ is a finite collection of balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show that there is a subcollection $\{B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\}_{k=1}^{l}$ of pairwise disjoint balls such that $$m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{l}B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\right) \geq 3^{-d} m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}B(x_{j},r_{j})\right)$$
where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

I want to constrain this problem by attempting to not trivialize it by applying a covering lemma.

Attempted proof: Suppose that $\{B(x_j,r_j)\}_{j=1}^{n}$ is a finite collection of balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $$\{B(x_j,r_j)\}_{j=1}^{n} \rightarrow \{B(x,r)\} \ \ \text{as} \ \ n\rightarrow \infty$$ Then there exists a subsequence of balls $\{B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\}_{j=1}^{n}$ such that $$\{B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\}_{j=1}^{n}\rightarrow \{B(x,r)\} \ \ \text{as} \ \ n,k\rightarrow \infty $$ Let $\delta = 3^{d}$, then choose an $x_{j_k},r_{j_k}$ such that $$|x_{j_k} - r_{j_k}| \leq \frac{(b - a)}{\delta}$$ where the subsequence $\{B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\}$ lies in the interval $[a,b]$. Then let $$A = \bigcup_{1}^{l}B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})$$ Since $\{B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\}$ is convergent and bounded, taking the Lebesgue measure it follows that $$m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{l}B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k})\right) \geq 3^{-d} m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{l}B(x_{j},r_{j})\right)$$

I am not sure if we can have balls just on some interval $[a,b]$ but I figured they could be on some place in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I am not sure if I can just conclude with that if I know it is convergent and bounded. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The $3$ actually does have a meaning here (it ist not just a random constant). This is no simple $\varepsilon - \delta$-thingie. You have to do some geometry here.

Comment: Hi I didn't understand the question at all. Can you tell me about a source where I can learn Lebesgue measure from? Thanks.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, the question is not really related to the Lebesgue measure. Just think of spheres and their volume or circles and their area. You could even think about intervals and their lengths.

Answer (score 2):

The $3$ does have some geometric meaning here. One can solve this exercise in the context of usual $3$-dimensional spheres or even $2$-dimension circles, since one only needs elementary geometric thoughts and no methods from measure theory.

It goes like this: Denote the balls by $B_1, \dotsc, B_n$.

In the first step, pick a ball $B_{j_1}$ with maximal size.

In the $k$-th step, pick a ball $B_{j_k}$ with maximal size among these, which are disjoint to $B_{j_1} \cup \dotsc \cup B_{j_{k-1}}$.

The process stops at some point, not later than at the $n$-th step. Nevertheless one can show that the desired inequality holds, when the proess stops.

The key is the following observation: Say the process stopped after $s$ steps, i.e. we have obtained the disjoint collection $B_{j_1}, \dotsc, B_{j_s}$.

By construction, any ball $B_i$ meets some $B_{j_k}$ (since the process has stopped) and we have (if we assume $B_{j_k}$ maximal among these, who meet $B_i$) $r_{j_k} \geq r_i$ (if not, we could have picked $B_i$ in the $k$-th step instead of $B_{j_k}$). Hence we get the punchline: $B_i$ is contained in $B(x_{j_k},3r_{j_k})$, note the **three**.

Now you can see, where the $3^d$ comes into play, because we have $m(B(x_{j_k},3r_{j_k}))=3^d \cdot m(B(x_{j_k},r_{j_k}))$.

Comment: You must have misunderstood me. What precisely has set you up?

Comment: Actually I defended you, when i blamed the author of the exercise to do it in the context of measure theory. This was not meant to offend you at all.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood you. I just thought the way you said my approach was not even close was offensive even if that is the case, which I am sure it is I was up late so half asleep while I was doing it

Comment: Ok, then sorry for these words. I just wanted to point out, whats really happening here. I will edit it.

Comment: no problem, dont worry about it

Comment: Glad to have solved this issue.